# Loading Access Data into DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a MS Access Database as a connection in my Visual Studio project. It automatically generated some code when I added the connection:

```
private void CruncherForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'wcMainDBDataSet.stations_NOAA' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.stations_NOAATableAdapter.Fill(this.wcMainDBDataSet.stations_NOAA);
}
```

I have modified that code to below:

```
private void CruncherForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'wcMainDBDataSet.stations_NOAA' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.stations_NOAATableAdapter.Fill(this.wcMainDBDataSet.stations_NOAA);

    foreach (var row in this.wcMainDBDataSet.stations_NOAA.Rows)
    {
        this.wthrDB.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

`wthrDB` is my DataGridView. I'm not getting the 2 rows from my Access database in my data grid. What is the proper way to do this?

A thought:
Is some linking between the columns needed? I have 9 defined columns in my Data Grid View & 10 in the Access file if you count the ID (primary key) column Access auto-generates. If so, how is it done in a data source scenario?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: There is very little information here to help you. Let's start with - when you debug this do you enter the loop or are there no rows in the DataTable? If not, check the connection string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataGridView has DataSource property, which can be set to DataTable. Make sure that it actually contains some rows (set a breakpoint in CruncherForm_Load method and inspect stations_NOAA in debug mode)

```
private void CruncherForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.stations_NOAATableAdapter.Fill(this.wcMainDBDataSet.stations_NOAA);

    this.wthrDB.DataSource = this.wcMainDBDataSet.stations_NOAA;
}
```

also it might be necessary to assign [DataPropertyName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname) to DataGridView columns